# Building a minimum DAO in front of a search engine

Tags: java, hibernate, crud, dao, hibernate-search

Question 1: CRUD goes in a DAO but also finders, rigth?
Question 2: Search engine extenstions, like Hibernate Search, is it normal to write their functionality into the DAO?

Comment: The second answer is good. I'll wait a few days for others, and then choose, howver. Thank you for both answers so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes to both since your DAO is about Data Access for a Specific Object which includes all CRUD and Searching Operations.

Answer (score 0):

It can, yes -- for both questions. The important point to remember is that the intent of your DAO is to abstract the details of your persistence scheme from the rest of your application. It is easy, especially once you start getting into searching and more complex operations, to start introducing coupling to your persistence implementation. For example, if you expose searching via methods with Hibernate Criteria as parameters, you introduce a coupling to Hibernate. This may or may not be ok or appropriate for your app.

Another strategy would be to have different DAOs for CRUD and query operations, and then combine those two in a higher layer abstraction or Service. I've seen this at times used for apps that have a relational db and a Lucene index, for example.